# how to execute multiple update queries in PHP using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to execute multiple update queries in single query using mysql_query() funciton of PHP.
I append multiple update statements to form single query to pass parameter to mysql_query() function. So at the end I am getting one combined query but it is found to be wrong. When I run that query at that time during execution I am getting error as "Invalid query". I do not understand what is wrong happening , so please help me in this quetion . I am suffering from it so badly. I tried my best. I am giving my code for reference.

Here I am getting values of varibles through querystring

my querystirng : `localhost/ticker/publish-ticker.php?i=1,2,3&j=3,4`

```
if(isset($_GET['i']))
{
    $selected_tickers = $_GET['i']; 
}

if(isset($_GET['j']))
{
    $selected_twitters = $_GET['j'];    
}
```

Here I am forming the query

```
$sql2 = "";
if(count($sel_ticker_array) > 0 )
{
foreach($sel_ticker_array as $value2)
{
    $tid1 = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','', $value2);                               
    $sql2 .= "update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=0 where id!=$tid1;";

}



foreach($sel_ticker_array as $value)
{
    $tid3 = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','', $value);                                
    $sql2 .= "update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=1,last_used='$todaysdate' where id=$tid3;";

}

}


if(count($sel_twitter_array) > 0)
{
foreach($sel_twitter_array as $value)
{
    $tid = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','', $value);                             
    $sql2 .= "update tbl_ticker2 set twitter_flag=0 where id!=$tid;";

}



foreach($sel_twitter_array as $value)
{
    $tid = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','', $value);                             
    $sql2 .= "update tbl_ticker2 set twitter_flag=1,last_used='$todaysdate' where id=$tid;";

}
}
```

Here I am executing it but I am getting output as "Invalid query"

```
$query3 = mysql_query($sql2);

    if(!$query3)
    {
        die("Invalid Delivery");
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert("Ticker Updated Successfully");';
        echo 'location.href="add_ticker.php"';
        echo '</script>';         

    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: let me get the "you should be using pdo or mysqli" out of the way

Comment: You can't run multiple queries in a single call using `mysql_query`. If you want to do that, you need to use `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Comment: you may want to look at making use of SQL "IN" statements such as `update tbl_ticker2 set twitter_flag=1,last_used='$todaysdate' where id in ($tid1,$tid2,$tid3);`  then take a look at having your foreach statements build the list of conditions matching the statement

Comment: okay @andrewsi ....I will use mysqli_multi_query()....but for that...how should I combine multiple statements into single one ?

Comment: @andrewsi I am getting wrong combined query.So please check that also.

Comment: @Yogeshk - you can't just use that function, without changing your code to use `mysqli_*` throughout. Once you've done that, you can pass a list of semi-colon separated SQL statements into the function.

Comment: @andrewsi Thats okay...but main problem is also in appending multiple queries into one. Actully problem is when my query starts appending at that time, when $sql2 executes two time then it will produce following result update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=0 where id!=1;
update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=0 where id!=1;update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=0 where id!=2;
update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=0 where id!=1;update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=0 where id!=2;update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=0 where id!=3; which is invalid

Comment: @andrewsi actully result of $sql2 after executing two times is only like this :    update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=0 where id!=1;update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=0 where id!=2;update tbl_ticker2 set ticker_flag=0 where id!=3;

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using the regular mysql-api in PHP.

[mysql_query()](https://php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

it can be done using mysqli and the [mysqli_multi_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) function.

also read :

- [PHP: Multiple Statements - Manual](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

Answer (score 0):

Manual states that you cannot use it for multiple queries.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

You can use mysqli or pdo for this.

Comment: I know it's possible using mysqli, but I didn't know it was possible with PDO - do you have a link?